# JSON.stringify turned the value array into a string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JS object

```
{
    aString:[aNumber, aURL]
}
```

JSON.stringify() returns

```
{
    "aString":"[number, \"aURL\"]"
}
```

I thought that valid JSON can have arrays as values. Can I have stringify return the JSON string without converting the array into a string? Basically I need turn the whole JS object straight into a string, without any modification.

Is there a better way to do this? I've been looking around but everyone suggests using JSON.stringify if I want an object to string, and no one has raised this problem.

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses. Here is how I created my JS object, please let me know if I messed up and how!

```
cookie = {};
// productURL is a string, timer is a number, imageSrc is a URL string
cookie[productURL] = [timer, imageSrc];
// then, I just stringified cookie
newCookie = JSON.stringify(cookie);
```

If it is also relevant, I am setting an actual cookie's value as the resulting JSON string, in order to access it in another set of functions. Setting the cookie's value does do some URI encoding of its own, but I've actually been grabbing the value of newCookie in the Chrome console as well and it also returns the Array as a string.

Comment: It sounds like `[aNumber, aURL]` was already a JSON string, so you're stringifying it twice.

Comment: Show how you created the JS object.

Comment: I've added some notes in my edit. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If an object you're trying to stringify has a `toJSON` function, that will be called by `JSON.stringify`. Most likely you have an external library that's adding Array.prototype.toJSON.

For example, an old version (1.6) of Prototype JS will "conveniently" add that for you.

**Prototype 1.6.1**:

```js
alert(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.min.js"></script>
```

Whereas a newer version will not.

**Prototype 1.7.2**:

```js
alert(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2/prototype.min.js"></script>
```

You could try deleting `Array.prototype.toJSON` just to see if that's what's causing the problem. If it is, you might want to look into upgrading/deprecating any libraries in your code that do weird things like that.

**Prototype 1.6.1 (after deleting `toJSON`)**

```js
delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
alert(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. I've tested your hypothesis and it is indeed true. I don't have 100% control or knowledge over the source code, as it is a client's site, so I had no idea. Now I know :) I will tell them to upgrade their prototype.js library.

Comment: Keep in mind that the last update to prototype.js was about a year ago, and the last update before about two years before that. You can see the revision history here: http://prototypejs.org/download/. There seem to be a few recent commits on their github page, but it might be worth looking into another library that is more actively developed unless the code heavily depends on Prototype.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will suggest that to the client, as prototype.js may cause future headaches for them and their partners. At the end of the day it will be their decision though... I am not building their site, just implementing an ad platform.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description this is not what should happen.

If you have code like this:

```
var obj = {
    aString:[123, "test"]
}

document.getElementById("out").value = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

it will generate the expected json:

```
{"aString":[123,"test"]}
```

also see https://jsfiddle.net/zudrrc13/

in order to produce your output the original object would have to look something like:

```
var obj = {
    aString:"[123, \"test\"]"
}
```